# Visual Studio Project Character Set

Tags: visual-studio

How can one change the character set of a vs project from Multibyte to Unicode?

In Visual Studio 2019 Edition, I tried looking at Project Properties -> General, yet I saw no character set option

[image]

Does that option still exist in VS2019? If not, how can one still change the character set?

Answer (score 1):

*Found the solution!*

It was moved to the Advanced Tab in VS2019 ;)

[image]